# IFormFile file to binary file C#

Tags: c#, .net, post, binary, httpclient

Ive got an api which accepts json and a file as body. The body is accepted in binary format. On my backed im getting the file as `IFormFile` type file. Api is not giving me the expected results and i guess thats because im not sending the right data.
How i am sending the file to the httpClient:

```
var content = new MultipartFormDataContent();
var fileContent = new StreamContent(file.openReadStream());
fileContent.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse(file.ContentType);
content.Add(fileContent, "file", file.FileName);
var httpResponse = await client.PostAsync(url, content);
var response = await httpResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
return response
```

Based on the result i am getting it seems that it always getting the file as empty. Do anyone how i can convert my file to binary?

[api](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ZAhf.png)

postman curl

```
var client = new HttpClient();

var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, url);
request.Headers.Add("requestId", "");  
request.Headers.Add("originChannelId", "");    
request.Headers.Add("journeyId", "");   
request.Headers.Add("timeStamp", "");    
request.Headers.Add("originSourceId", "");    
request.Headers.Add("originUserId", "");    
request.Headers.Add("Cookie", "");    
var content = new MultipartFormDataContent();   
content.Add(new StreamContent(File.OpenRead("/C:/Users/user/Downloads/scanMethods.json")), "scanMethods", "/C:/Users/5948/Downloads/scanMethods.json");    
content.Add(new StreamContent(File.OpenRead("/C:/Users/user/Downloads/test.docx")), "file", "/C:/Users/5948/Downloads/test.docx");
request.Content = content;   
var response = await client.SendAsync(request);   
response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();   
Console.WriteLine(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
```

I am expecting a different value when file is empty and when the file is not.

Comment: don't use `ReadAsStringAsync`.

Comment: @DanielA.White why? what should i use?

Comment: because you said its a binary file. it might not be convertible to a string

Comment: @DanielA.White the api body accepts a binary file, thats the response

Comment: Have you looked at the response code? I bet you it's something other than 200.

Comment: no its 200 with the wrong message

Comment: @GuruStron how can i use ReadAllBytes when i have not a path for the file? because im getting the file as a paremeter. there is not path

Comment: When you have multiple items in a body it is a MIME attachment.  Each MIME attachment start with two dashes on a new line.  You do not need to convert to binary.  See following for sample of MIME : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/exchange-server-2010/aa563375(v=exchg.140)?force_isolation=true

Comment: this is not the issue. it seems that the api is not reading properly the file.

Comment: @John is it reading it correctly when the endpoint is invoked via Swagger UI?

Comment: im using the postman and everything seems to be ok

Comment: Can you please share curl request from Postman (for example via "Code" button on the right near send button)?

Comment: @John I don't see the curl code.